# Rails nested forms: assign index as value to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, html, erb

I'm building a booking system for hotels and created a price model, which is accepted by the room model as nested attributes. So far so good, everything works perfectly fine. However, since I want to give the opportunity to be able to maintain price increments, I need the responding days in my price model. So basically, price: 50, 80, 120 along with days: 1, 2, 3 ...ok, so now my question: how can I achieve that the days are saved automatically in the price table, so that the user only needs to enter the price for a specific day.

I've tried to get it working with a hidden field that submits to the days column, but I couldn't fix it. As I have 20 increments generated by the controller, I've tried it with the index generated by the fields_for helper.

here's the relevant part of my **controller:**

```
def new
    @room = current_user.rooms.build
    20.times do 
     increment = @room.increments.build
    end
end
```

And here's my **view**:

```
<%= form_for @room do |f| %>
  #...
  <%= f.fields_for :increments do |ff| %>

      <%= ff.text_field :price, placeholder: 'price' %>
      <%= ff.hidden_field :days, value: 'index'  %>
```

Do you have any ideas how I could achieve to get the value of my hidden_field to equal 1...20 with respect of my controller that generates 20 price fields? Do I need to write a form helper and if yes, how could I get it to add the number of days? Am I totally wrong with my approach and there is a more obvious way to achieve the same functionality? Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you're asking, but could you use something like:

```
def new
    @room = current_user.rooms.build
    (1..20).each do |i|
      @center.increments.build(days: i)
    end
end
```

Or the building in a single line:

`(1..20).each { |i| @center.increments.build(days: i) }`

(Assigning `increment` in the loop isn't used anywhere, and will update to the last new increment for each element of the loop; therefore I've removed it.)

Edit: what @oscar said...

Comment: Using `(1..20)` is much more elegant than `20.times`

Answer (score 0):

Do you always want to generate 20 times increments ?

well this line `20.times do` is a loop. What would I do will be something like:

```
20.times do |t|
 increment = @center.increments.build(days: t+1) # t+1 since t starts in 0
end
```

In this way you set up the days at the building of the instances